# Test case for checking the font color and style for uilabel using Appium for native ios application

Tags: java, ios, macos, native, appium

I want to test ui design of native iOS application. For that I am using Appium framework. Functional testing is working fine. To write the test cases I used Java with eclipse. 
Please tell me how can I write test script for checking label color and font?

Answer (score 0):

Does your element has any color attribute?
if yes then you can use below command

```
String color=driver.findElement(By.id("something")).getAttribute("color-attribute");
```

Comment: color attribute!! am i missing something here ? : https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-